# Summing two columns where they share interval overlap

Tags: python, pybedtools, pyranges

I have two bed files where each column has a numeric score. I want to sum these numbers where there is overlap between the two bed files. How do I do that? Also, I am only interested in the score in specific genes.

Here is my setup:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
import pyranges as pr
import pandas as pd

entries = int(1e6)
cpg1 = pr.random(entries)
cpg2 = pr.random(entries)

cpg1.CPG = np.random.randint(100, size=entries)
cpg2.CPG = np.random.randint(100, size=entries)

regulatory_elements = pr.random(int(1e5), length=int(1e4))
regulatory_elements.Gene = np.arange(len(regulatory_elements), dtype=int)
```

So my data looks like:

```
cpg1
# +--------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
# | Chromosome   | Start     | End       | Strand       | CPG       |
# | (category)   | (int32)   | (int32)   | (category)   | (int64)   |
# |--------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+-----------|
# | chr1         | 8830650   | 8830750   | +            | 72        |
# | chr1         | 9564361   | 9564461   | +            | 57        |
# | chr1         | 44977425  | 44977525  | +            | 99        |
# | chr1         | 239741543 | 239741643 | +            | 54        |
# | ...          | ...       | ...       | ...          | ...       |
# | chrY         | 29437476  | 29437576  | -            | 44        |
# | chrY         | 49995298  | 49995398  | -            | 43        |
# | chrY         | 50840129  | 50840229  | -            | 10        |
# | chrY         | 38069647  | 38069747  | -            | 89        |
# +--------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
# Stranded PyRanges object has 1,000,000 rows and 5 columns from 25 chromosomes.
# For printing, the PyRanges was sorted on Chromosome and Strand.


regulatory_elements
# +--------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
# | Chromosome   | Start     | End       | Strand       | Gene      |
# | (category)   | (int32)   | (int32)   | (category)   | (int64)   |
# |--------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+-----------|
# | chr1         | 217921634 | 217931634 | +            | 0         |
# | chr1         | 166226804 | 166236804 | +            | 1         |
# | chr1         | 170688210 | 170698210 | +            | 2         |
# | chr1         | 57958563  | 57968563  | +            | 3         |
# | ...          | ...       | ...       | ...          | ...       |
# | chrY         | 35870043  | 35880043  | -            | 99996     |
# | chrY         | 35057634  | 35067634  | -            | 99997     |
# | chrY         | 52718975  | 52728975  | -            | 99998     |
# | chrY         | 19196507  | 19206507  | -            | 99999     |
# +--------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
# Stranded PyRanges object has 100,000 rows and 5 columns from 25 chromosomes.
# For printing, the PyRanges was sorted on Chromosome and Strand.
```

(This is a q from privateish correspondence).

Comment: Mods: would love tags for pandas, pyranges and run-length-encodings. All three have tags on SO you can copy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to sum two columns based on overlaps, converting them to RLEs is a good idea.

```
# get the cpg scores only where there is overlap with the genes you are interested in 
cr1 = cpg1.join(regulatory_elements).new_position("intersection").drop(like="_(a|b)")
cr2 = cpg2.join(regulatory_elements).new_position("intersection").drop(like="_(a|b)")

# convert these to run length encodings, using the score from the CPG column
rle1 = cr1.to_rle("CPG", rpm=False)
rle2 = cr2.to_rle("CPG", rpm=False)

rle_sum = rle1 + rle2

# convert the rles back to ranges
# (I will give the to_ranges function an option dtype eventually)
range_sum = rle_sum.to_ranges().apply(lambda df: df.astype({"Start": np.int32, "End": np.int32}))

# add the gene names to the scores
gr = range_sum.join(regulatory_elements) # .drop(like="_b")
```

Now the result is:

```
print(gr)
# +--------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
# | Chromosome   | Start     | End       | Score       | Strand     | Start_b   | End_b     | Strand_b     | Gene      |
# | (object)     | (int32)   | (int32)   | (float64)   | (object)   | (int32)   | (int32)   | (category)   | (int64)   |
# |--------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+-----------|
# | chr1         | 15623     | 15723     | 77.0        | +          | 9886      | 19886     | +            | 3714      |
# | chr1         | 16034     | 16134     | 84.0        | +          | 9886      | 19886     | +            | 3714      |
# | chr1         | 36588     | 36688     | 2.0         | +          | 36479     | 46479     | +            | 2871      |
# | chr1         | 37271     | 37371     | 30.0        | +          | 36479     | 46479     | +            | 2871      |
# | ...          | ...       | ...       | ...         | ...        | ...       | ...       | ...          | ...       |
# | chrY         | 59312851  | 59312951  | 28.0        | -          | 59308107  | 59318107  | +            | 98599     |
# | chrY         | 59332843  | 59332943  | 82.0        | -          | 59332664  | 59342664  | -            | 99215     |
# | chrY         | 59337592  | 59337692  | 41.0        | -          | 59332664  | 59342664  | -            | 99215     |
# | chrY         | 59341719  | 59341819  | 15.0        | -          | 59332664  | 59342664  | -            | 99215     |
# +--------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
# Stranded PyRanges object has 668,317 rows and 9 columns from 25 chromosomes.
# For printing, the PyRanges was sorted on Chromosome and Strand.

print(gr[gr.Score > 100])
# +--------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
# | Chromosome   | Start     | End       | Score       | Strand     | Start_b   | End_b     | Strand_b     | Gene      |
# | (object)     | (int32)   | (int32)   | (float64)   | (object)   | (int32)   | (int32)   | (category)   | (int64)   |
# |--------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+-----------|
# | chr1         | 96874     | 96974     | 116.0       | +          | 87668     | 97668     | -            | 7391      |
# | chr1         | 96874     | 96974     | 116.0       | +          | 89794     | 99794     | -            | 6357      |
# | chr1         | 749686    | 749697    | 180.0       | +          | 744041    | 754041    | +            | 1150      |
# | chr1         | 749686    | 749697    | 180.0       | +          | 749277    | 759277    | -            | 6395      |
# | ...          | ...       | ...       | ...         | ...        | ...       | ...       | ...          | ...       |
# | chrY         | 59060667  | 59060767  | 196.0       | -          | 59052942  | 59062942  | -            | 99957     |
# | chrY         | 59060667  | 59060767  | 196.0       | -          | 59059904  | 59069904  | +            | 98401     |
# | chrY         | 59063570  | 59063576  | 105.0       | -          | 59059904  | 59069904  | +            | 98401     |
# | chrY         | 59269010  | 59269085  | 152.0       | -          | 59264704  | 59274704  | -            | 99499     |
# +--------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
# Stranded PyRanges object has 106,643 rows and 9 columns from 25 chromosomes.
# For printing, the PyRanges was sorted on Chromosome and Strand.
```